# How to only have one display?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I have a laptop that is hooked up to a monitor via a VGA cable.  I'm trying to get the display set to the external monitor only (I don't want any display on the laptop screen).  However, whenever I set the laptop display to "off" in the "Displays" setting, their isn't a display on either (the laptop screen and the monitor have no signal).  So, how do I get it to where the display only shows up on the external monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xrandr` to change the default primary monitor.

> Turns out `xrandr --output DFP1 --primary` does the trick. Replace
>   DFP1 to the name of the monitor you want to make your primary monitor.
>   You can run `xrandr --prop` to get the proper names of the monitors
>   currently connected.
>
> If you run `xrandr --output DFP1 --primary`, it does switch the
>   primary monitors, but once you restart your laptop, the laptop becomes
>   the primary display once again.
>
> So, I thought I would write a simple script, that runs at start up,
>   which checks, if there is an external monitor connected, and if there
>   is, then run the command to make the external monitor the primary
>   display.
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> NR_OF_MONITORS=$(xrandr -d :0 -q | grep ' connected' | wc -l)
> if [ $NR_OF_MONITORS = "2" ]; then
>   xrandr --output DFP1 --primary
> fi
> ```

[Source](http://milindshakya.tumblr.com/post/4952304640/setting-up-external-monitor-as-the-primary-monitor-in)